# attaching an angularjs directive to "bootstrap select"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap select widget in my angularjs app. I have a repeated pattern where I need to have the same select element in multiple forms. So I thought why not create that as a directive.

The code for the directive is below.

```
(function () {

var controller = function ($scope) { }

controller.$inject = ['$scope'];

var yesNoDecline = function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        template: '',
        controller: controller,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            //Only a select
            if ($(element).is('select')) {

                //Add options
                $(element).append($('<option />', {
                    value: 'No',
                    text: 'No'
                }));

                $(element).append($('<option />', {
                    value: 'Yes',
                    text: 'Yes'
                }));

                $(element).append($('<option />', {
                    value: 'Decline to answer',
                    text: 'Decline To Answer'
                }));

                $timeout(function () {
                    $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
                }, 0);

                //Add some attributes
                $(element).attr('ui-jq', 'selectpicker');
                $(element).attr('ui-options', '{ iconBase: "fa", tickIcon: "fa fa-check" }');
            }
        }
    }
};

yesNoDecline.$inject = ['$timeout'];

appModule.directive('yesNoDecline', yesNoDecline);
```

})();

Problems with the above code:

- Additional empty item is added at the top although the code above didn't add it.
- When I select "No" as an option, "Yes" is shown on the select. The same is true to other options, I select an option, another option appears selected.
- In the controller, I am setting the selected value to No on the $scope. However, nothing is selected on the select using this directive.

Here is another version of the code using pure Angular:
    I've converted this directive to a more angular-like. I get an error though multiple directives requesting same ngModel, which I don't get it frankly.

```
(function () {

var yesNoDecline = function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            name: '@',
            ngModel: '=ngModel'
        },

        template: '<select class="form-control bs-select" id="{{ ::id }}" name="{{ ::name }}" ng-model="ngModel.$viewValue" ' +
                  '     ui-jq="selectpicker" ui-options=\'{ iconBase: "fa", tickIcon: "fa fa-check" }\'>' +
                  '     <option ng-repeat="obj in data" value="{{ ::obj.value }}">{{ ::obj.text }}</option>' +
                  '</select>',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            //Populate the scope
            scope.data =
                [{
                    value: 'No', text: 'No'
                }, {
                    value: 'Yes', text: 'Yes'
                }, {
                    value: 'Decline to answer', text: 'Decline To Answer'
                }];

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
            }, function (newValue) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
                ngModelCtrl.$render();
            });

            $timeout(function () {
                $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
            }, 0);
        }
    }
};

yesNoDecline.$inject = ['$timeout'];
appModule.directive('yesNoDecline', yesNoDecline);
```

})();

That's how I use it:

```
<yes-no-decline id="x" name="x" ng-model="vm.y"></yes-no-decline>
```

I appreciate your assistance.

Thanks

Comment: I'm here just to shout: drop the jQuery

Comment: I totally understand. I am forced to use this control for now as I am using a certain framework that makes use of this. I might refactor later, but for now, I have to make it work.

Comment: Hey @MikkoViitala I made some changes to make it pure angular. can you have a look pls? Thanks